# Unable to compile RealTek RTL8188CE driver on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: drivers, compiling, realtek

I am trying to compile the Realtek drivers on my machine and I am getting the following errors:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build M=/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.o
/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.c: In function ‘rtl_action_proc’:
/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.c:885:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.freq = hw->conf.channel->center_freq;
                                ^
/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.c:886:32: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
       rx_status.band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                                ^
/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.c: In function ‘rtl_send_smps_action’:
/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.c:1451:24: error: ‘struct ieee80211_conf’ has no member named ‘channel’
   info->band = hw->conf.channel->band;
                        ^
make[2]: *** [/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/david/Downloads/rtl8188ce-linux-driver] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.11.0-12-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently the Linux headers have changed enough since 13.04 to break this driver.  After many days of work I have finally fixed the compile issues and gotten the driver working.  You can find the fixed driver, along with the detailing of all of my changes from the original version released by Realtek, at my Github repo here:  https://github.com/FreedomBen/rtl8188ce-linux-driver

For those who are interested, the biggest changes were the removal of `create_proc_entry()` and other related functions that put debugging information into the `/proc` directory.  I have not yet converted the code to use the replacement functions, so as of now the debug info will not be reported.  This does not in any way affect the performance of the driver though.

The other big change was the restructuring of [`struct ieee80211_hw`](http://wireless.kernel.org/80211books/API-struct-ieee80211-hw.html), [`struct ieee80211_conf`](http://wireless.kernel.org/80211books/API-struct-ieee80211-conf.html), and the addition of [`struct cfg80211_chan_def`](http://wireless.kernel.org/80211books/API-struct-ieee80211-conf.html) which replaced what used to be the `channel` member of `ieee80211_conf`.

There is also a new helper function [`cfg80211_get_chandef_type()`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=cfg80211_get_chandef_type) for retrieving channel type instead of the old direct method.

Comment: I'm getting the same error using the download from your git on base 14.04 kernel and since upgrading to 3.16. Thanks

Comment: @TahnoonPasha To be clear, you're on kernel 3.16?

Comment: Hi @FreedomBen. Thats right I'm on 3.16. I've since got it to compile but it shows up as using the old drivers with `./am_I_using_this_driver`....

Comment: @TahnoonPasha, thanks for the heads up.  I haven't yet added support for kernel 3.16.x but it looks like it's time.  Did you upgrade yourself or did Ubuntu push the upgrade through the normal repos?

Comment: Hi @Freedom_Ben, I upgraded myself. Continued to get persistent drop-offs the network after updating to your driver. Looked around the BB's and read that upgrading the kernel was one way to stabilize the driver so tried both. Surprise, surprise.. it didn't work. ;-) Still get drop-offs every 20 minutes or so and have to reconnect, but at least its a good connection when its on, since I compiled your patched driver. Thanks for your work on it.:-)

Comment: @Freedom_Ben, I saw somewhere that driver was proprietary, but if that's the case, then what exactly is proprietary about it? Does it contain binary blobs? Also, thanks a lot for your efforts in fixing this compilation issue; you helped me!

Comment: @n2liquid-GuilhermeVieira The Linux driver is not proprietary, it is in fact GPL.  There is a proprietary one for Windows though.

Answer (score 0):

rtl8188ce is no longer supported on kernel 3.9 & up.

I had the same WIFI card for my desktop.

The best cards for open source  support that I am now using is Atheros.

- Option #1 use "Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" as it supports rtl8188ce via rtl8192ce driver.
- Option#2 do your research on wifi cards that support open source kernels.
- Option #3 after doing research, use the card that will work with the latest kernel 3.12 & up.

After my experience with Realtek, I will not use them again as rtl8188ce is a poor card for Windows & Linux.

Comment: I understand the frustration but I don't think that the suggestions are practical short term, apologies and hence the rare down vote.