# Dual boot Windows 7 & Ubuntu 13.10 wifi problems

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, usb

My dual boot W7 & Ubuntu 13.10 system with ASUS PCE-N15 wireless card (on channel 1) will connect to Verizon Mifi 2200 while in W7 but not in Ubuntu.  Software requests password but after entering it, comes back repeatedly asking for it and not accepting it.

Also, and I dont believe these problems are connected, the USB 3.0 front connections work under Ubuntu and not under W7.  USB 2.0 work under both.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe better edit the question to loose the also. Besides it would be 2 questions it is also not about Ubuntu but about Windows.

Comment: Could you add the outcome of:
tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog |grep 'Net\|wpa\|kernel'
Just after you tried to login?

Comment: @CMM I have the same problem. Did you find any solution? What about this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292751/issues-installing-wireless-network-driver