# Why cant Ubuntu 14.04 connect to WIFI

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Got tired of Windows and Dual Boot, after completely installing Ubuntu on an old 2011 Hp G4 cannot connect via Wifi. I know that it has to be something small although I am still a noob. Can someone help me? I checked the drivers and there is no help i can find with my issue.

Comment: Probably this link can help you `http://askubuntu.com/questions/292751/issues-installing-wireless-network-driver`

Answer (score 0):

Many laptops need a hardwire connection to finish installing drivers to get the wireless up and running. Many times just a few commands can get you on your way.

Check for your WiFi card type by typing this command into a terminal (open a new terminal with **Ctrl**+**Alt**+**T**)...

```
lspci -vnn -d 14e4:
```

If you have one of the cards that shows as working here: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 then you can simply run the following commands with an ethernet connection to the Internet.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

If your device does not come up as green on the previous list, then you can try this guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>